# Samba on FreeNAS permission troubles

Tags: permissions, samba, freenas

I have a smbd 4.1.9 on FreeNAS 9.2.1.6 and having some permissions troubles. On the NAS there is a file as follows:

```
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 user1  SomeGroup        8820 Nov 27 15:59 file*
```

now, when I mount the share on which this file resides using CIFS through fstab:

```
//nas/share  /path/to/share cifs  username=user2,password=****,uid=user2,gid=user2  0   0
```

I can read the file, delete it, but not overwrite it:

```
[user2@localhost share$ cp somefile file
cp: cannot create regular file ‘file’: Permission denied
```

even though `user2` is member of the `SomeGroup` group that `file` belongs to. When I change the user-ownership of the file to `user2` it works fine.

The share in question is configured as follows:

```
force directory mode = 0775
force create mode = 0775
inherit owner = No
inherit acls = Yes
inherit permissions = Yes
profile acls = yes
nt acl support = no
browsable = No
valid users = +SomeGroup
```

I found out that using the `Apply Default Permissions` option (in FreeNAS) on the share fixes the issue, but when looking at the permissions, I don't really see what is going on "under the hood".